# Appdata folder while Upgrade Sitecore using Express Migration tool from 7.2 to 8.2

Tags: upgrade, express-migration-tool

We are working on to upgrade/migrate a application from 7.2 to 8.2 version using express migration tool 2.0. Database is in SQL Server 2012. While migrating, app data folder to the tune of 3 GB is created in destination website folder. Does this correct or we need to rerun the tool. Also can we delete this APPDATA folder while taking this to Final production deployment. Without APPDATA folder the total size of website folder is 700 MB.

Any suggestions...

Comment: What is in the appdata folder that is taking the disk space? Logs?

Comment: App_data folder has one folder called and MediaCache under which there are there folders Shell, Website and folder with hostname. These folders have many folders with name as 1, 2 3 etc. Each of these folders contains, JPG, PDF, Configuration files. These number goes up to 250

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting this folder you need to verify two things

1. Is this folder contain only "MediaCache" folder. If yes then you can go and delete this folder because this folder will automatically created once you run the website and visit some pages
2. If "App Data" folder contains "MediaCache" as well as "MediaFiles" folder then you can't delete the "MediaFiles" folder because some of the media item directly stored in this folder so if you delete this folder then your website is no longer able to display the image those are stored in this folder.
3. Please check your "temp" folder size.

Comment: App_data folder has one folder called and MediaCache under which there are there folders Shell, Website and folder with hostname. These folders have many folders with name as 1, 2 3 etc. Each of these folders contains, JPG, PDF, Configuration files. These number goes up to 250. The Temp folder size is only 1.10 MB.